# How to change video source onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

HTML:

```html
<div class="source" id="source_one" onclick="chnageToSourceTwo()">
    Source 1
</div>
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="none" width="640" height="360" poster="" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="example_video_1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

Script:

```js
function chnageToSourceTwo() {
    document.getElementById("example_video_1").src="example_video_2.mp4";
}
```

The video source is not changing after clicking on div. I am using the Video.js plugin to add video player to my webpage.

Does anyone know how to change source of video onclick?

**jsFiddle**  http://jsfiddle.net/ah1fj7te/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier is to give your `<source>` object an ID. and reference the object by the ID using [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) and [`document.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Change your HTML:

```
<div class="source" id="source_one">Source 1</div>
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="none" width="640" height="360" poster="" data-setup="{}">
    <source id="source_video" src="example_video_1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>

<script>
  document.getElementById('source_one').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('source_video').src = 'example_video_2.mp4';
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
document.getElementById("example_video_1").src="example_video_2.mp4";
```

With this:

```
document.getElementById("example_video_1").getElementsByTagName('source')[0].src="example_video_2.mp4";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/michael_0815/nsu77w92/2/)

And here some code:

```
var a = document.getElementById('source_one');
a.addEventListener('click',function() {
document.getElementById("example_video_1").children[0].src="example_video_2.mp4";
a.innerHTML = 'Source 2';
alert(document.getElementById('example_video_1').children[0].src); // just to show that it is changed...
});
```

**If you want to be able to toggle both videos, use this:**

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/michael_0815/nsu77w92/3/)

```
var a = document.getElementById('source_one');
var b = document.getElementById("example_video_1");
a.addEventListener('click',function() {
    if (document.getElementById("example_video_1").children[0].src == 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/example_video_2.mp4') // replace with real url
 {
    document.getElementById("example_video_1").children[0].src="example_video_1.mp4";
    a.innerHTML = 'Source 1';
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById("example_video_1").children[0].src="example_video_2.mp4";
    a.innerHTML = 'Source 2'; 
    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you tagged this as jQuery, so here is how you would implement this in jQuery.

```
$("#example_video_1 source").attr("src", "example_video_2.mp4");
```

Comment: You need to remove 'source' from the selector.

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like the source tag is what has the src attribute.