# How to change video js source with a link click

Tags: javascript, html, video, video.js

I'm trying to create a simple website with few anime episodes. I have a question about javascript. How can I change video source by clicking on one of my links? I understand, that I have to use event listeners and just change the `<source>` depending on what link I click, but I'm not that good at programing or googeling.
The video player I'm using is "video js".

If I could get an help I'd be really thankful.

the section of video code:

```
        <div class="sidebar">
            <a href="">Episode 1</a>
            <a href="">Episode 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <h1>Click the "play button" to start watching!</h1>
            <video
            id="my_video"
            class="video-js"
            controls
            preload="auto"
            width="640"
            height="300"
            poster="bg2.jpg"
            data-setup="{}">
            <source src="1-1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <source src="1-1.webm" type="video/webm" />
            <p class="vjs-no-js">
                To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
                web browser that
            <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
            </p>
            </video>
        </div>
```

I would add the javascript file too, but my brain can't write anything useful there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find enclosed a small demo and the code.

https://codepen.io/hellomartin-the-scripter/pen/GRZLXJv

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeSource('1-1')">Episode 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="changeSource('1-2')">Episode 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="changeSource('1-3')">Episode 3</a>

<!-- SOURCE TAGS -->
<source id="video-mp4" src="#" />
<source id="video-webm" src="#" />
```

Script:

```
function changeSource(episode) {
  document.getElementById("video-mp4").src=episode + '.mp4';
  document.getElementById("video-webm").src=episode + '.webm';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:


Javascript:

```js
function ChangeSrc(Src) {
    document.getElementById('my_video').src = Src + '.mp4';
}
```

HTML:

```html
<a onclick="changeSrc('1')">Episode 1</a>
<a onclick="changeSrc('2')">Episode 2</a>
```

Oh sorry, someone already answered something like this. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Answer by Ryan in this post can help you with this problem:
[How to change video source onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27140952/how-to-change-video-source-onclick)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the source an element id and then use getElementbyid command to modify it and that should work like it does in the answer of this question

[How to change video source onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27140952/how-to-change-video-source-onclick)